# Memory calculation of objects inaccurate?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm creating a small cache daemon, and I want to limit its memory usage to *approximately* a specified amount. However, there seems to be an issue just trying to calculate how much memory is in use.

Every time a CacheEntry object is created, it adds the size of a CacheEntry object (apparently 64 bytes) *plus* the number of bytes used in internal arrays to the counter for how many bytes are in use. When the CacheEntry object is deleted, it subtracts that amount. I can confirm that the math, at least, is correct.

However, when run inside NetBeans, the memory profiler reports *vastly* different numbers. Roughly twice as high, to be specific. It is not a memory leak, and it is specifically related to the amount of CacheEntry objects *currently* in existence. Increasing the amount of data stored in the internal arrays actually brings the numbers closer together (as opposed to further apart, if that were being improperly calculated); from this, I have concluded that the overhead of having a CacheEntry object in memory is almost twice what sizeof() is reporting. It does not rise in steps or "chunks".

Is there some common reason why this might happen?

**UPDATE:** Just to check, I ran my tests without a profiler in place. Linux reports the same VmHWM/VmRSS either way, so the memory profiler is definitely not affecting the calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This memory bloat is caused by use of `new`, specifically on relatively small objects. On Windows, dynamically allocated memory incurs a 16- or 24-byte overhead each time; I haven't found the exact numbers for Linux, but it's roughly the same. This is because each allocated chunk needs to record its location and size (possibly more than once) so that it can be accurately freed later.

As far as I'm aware, the running program also does not know exactly how much overhead is involved in this, at least in any way accessible to the programmer.

Generally speaking, large quantities of small objects should use a memory pool, both for speed and memory conservation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the profiler is adding reference objects to track the objects? Do you see the same results when you run the application in release vs Debug?

Comment: Hmm, not a bad idea, but in this case, the usage (and difference) is identical either way.

Comment: I was pretty sure though that profilers work by replacing malloc with their own debug version though to help profile?

Comment: They very well might - but I'm going to guess that they also compensate for that internally. Memory profiling would be completely useless if it substantially altered what was being measured in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some common reason why this might happen?

Yeah, that could be internal fragmentation and overhead of the memory manager. If your data type is small (eg. `sizeof(CacheEntry)` is 8 bytes), `new`ing such data type might produce a bigger chunk of memory. It is partly used for malloc's internal bookkeeping (it usually stores the size of the block somewhere), partly for padding needed to align your data type on its natural boundary (eg. 8 bytes data + 4 bytes bookkeeping + 4 bytes padding needed to align the whole thing on 8-byte boundary).

You can solve it by allocating from a single continuous array of CacheEntry (eg. `CacheEntry array[1000]` takes exactly `1000*sizeof(CacheEntry)` bytes). You'd have to track the usage of the individual elements in the array, but that should be doable without additional memory. (eg. by running a free-list of entries in the place of the free entries).

Comment: Hmm, that's a problem, as this program relies upon a doubly-linked-list structure with lots of `new` and `delete`. Is there any way to know exactly how much bookkeeping and padding there is? I don't necessarily need to _reduce_ memory usage, only track it.